# Mongoose filter elements from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a location document which stores a few locations aswell as measurements for the temperature and the timestamp when they were taken, I want to keep my code clean and want to filter the measurements which fit an interval in time. When I try.. I get all the measurements, which is not the desired result.
Here is my schema for Location.

```
const LocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  location: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  latitude: { 
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: -90,
    max: 90
  },
  longitude: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: -180,
    max: 180
  },
  measurements: [{
    timestamp: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    temperature:{
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }

  }] 
});
```

Here is my attempt to filter measurements.

```
var locations = await Location.find({
                'measurements': {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        timestamp: {
                            $gte: req.query.from,
                            $lte: req.query.to
                        }
                    }
                } 
            });
```

Comment: Actually since you're using Mongoose, you have to query using `Location.find().elemMatch()`

Comment: See more [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-elemMatch)

Comment: elemMatch() must be used after where() when called with these arguments

Comment: @dubonzi doesnt seem to work

Comment: Try it like this. `Location.find().where('measurements', { timestamp: { $gte: req.query.from, $lte: req.query.to}}).exec().then((results) => {//do something})`

Comment: @dubonzi -  Now I get error: Cast to Number failed for value \"{ '$gte': 1523132742285, '$lte': 1523132754212 }\" at path \"timestamp\" for model \"Location\"

Comment: My bad, it should be `find().elemMatch(...` instead of `find().where(...`

Comment: No error, but I get all results, no sign on filtering.

Comment: Are you sure the values of `req.query.from` and `req.query.to` are correct?

Comment: Yeah. they are good.